# Rcpp exported module not exposed

Tags: c++, r, module, rcpp

I have an R package called multicool which handles permutations of multisets. Currently, internally, there exists a C++ class, and a call to initMC creates a new object of class Multicool which then can do all the things I need it to do. However, there is no simple way to release the memory allocated to this object. It doesn't matter for simple uses, but I have an application which might call this hundreds of thousands of times.

The solution, I think, is to expose the class to R using an Rcpp Module. However, I have tried following the instructions and I get the error:

Error: object 'mcModule' not found

Initially - I would just like to expose the object and its constructor. This is my class definition

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

class Multicool{
  struct list_el {
    int v;
    struct list_el * n;
  };
  typedef struct list_el item;

  item *h;
  item *t;
  item *i;

  int *m_pnInitialState; 
  int *m_pnCurrState;
  int m_nLength;
  bool m_bFirst;

  public:
   // constructor
  Multicool(IntegerVector x){
    int nx = (int)x.size();
  }
};
```

and then I export the class and the constructor with

```
RCPP_MODULE(mcModule){
  using namespace Rcpp;

  class_<Multicool>("Multicool")

  .constructor<IntegerVector>()
  ;
}
```

I have added the line

```
import(Rcpp)
```

to my NAMESPACE file

I have added

```
RcppModules: mcModule
```

to my DESCRIPTION file

and I have added a call to loadRcppModules in the .onLoad function

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
  loadRcppModules()
}
```

All of this compiles and the package builds without complaint. But when I got to create a new Multicool object I get the aforementioned error

```
> library(multicool)
> Multicool = mcModule$Multicool
Error: object 'mcModule' not found
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated

Comment: Did you see my additional edits?

Comment: Yes thanks @dirk-eddelbuettel

Answer (score 4):

You generally need a `new` call first.  See in my RcppRedis package:

```
RCPP_MODULE(Redis) {
    Rcpp::class_<Redis>("Redis")   

        .constructor("default constructor")  
        [...stuff omitted for brevity...]

    ;
}
```

where the R code (eg in the `demo/` directory) does

```
suppressMessages(library(RcppRedis))

redis <- new(Redis)
```

after which you can access functions `redis$foo()` etc that are part of the module.

So try adding

```
mcModule <- new(mcModule)
```

before accessing `mcModule$Multicool`.

*Edit:* Looks like you were missing the `loadModule("mcModule", TRUE)` call.

*Edit 2:* To be more explicit, I added your file to the (working) `testRcppModule` from the package and made the one change you made (to `DESCRIPTION`) and one more to an R file to load the module:

```
edd@max:/tmp/rcpp/module$ diff -ru ~/git/rcpp/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule/  testRcppModule/ 
diff -ru /home/edd/git/rcpp/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule/DESCRIPTION testRcppModule/DESCRIPTION
--- /home/edd/git/rcpp/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule/DESCRIPTION        2015-08-26 15:53:03.891830292 -0500
+++ testRcppModule/DESCRIPTION  2015-10-22 21:34:23.716959638 -0500
@@ -10,6 +10,6 @@
 LazyLoad: yes
 Depends: methods, Rcpp (>= 0.8.5)
 LinkingTo: Rcpp
-RcppModules: RcppModuleWorld, stdVector, NumEx
+RcppModules: RcppModuleWorld, stdVector, NumEx, mcModule
 Packaged: 2010-09-09 18:42:28 UTC; jmc

diff -ru /home/edd/git/rcpp/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule/R/zzz.R testRcppModule/R/zzz.R
--- /home/edd/git/rcpp/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule/R/zzz.R    2015-08-26 15:53:03.891830292 -0500
+++ testRcppModule/R/zzz.R      2015-10-22 21:41:41.468532838 -0500
@@ -8,4 +8,5 @@
 loadModule("RcppModuleNumEx", TRUE)
 loadModule("RcppModuleWorld", TRUE)
 loadModule("stdVector", TRUE)
+loadModule("mcModule", TRUE)

Only in testRcppModule/src: multicool.cpp
edd@max:/tmp/rcpp/module$
```

With that, all is good:

```
$ r --package testRcppModule --eval 'm <- new(mcModule); print(m)'
C++ object <0x757d18> of class 'mcModule' <0x1adeab0>
$
```

Comment: Thanks @dirk-eddelbuettel - that gets me one step further but still an error:
`> mcModule <- new(mcModule)`
`Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where, resolve.msg = resolve.msg) :
  object 'mcModule' not found`

Comment: Take it one step back then, look at the (shipped, tried, tested) [set of files of the unit test example package](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/tree/master/inst/unitTests/testRcppModule) (which is also part of your installation) and modify it.  I personally prefer that over starting from scratch.  I also often keep the module name equal to class name to not confuse myself over which I need...

Comment: Thanks Dirk (@dirk-eddelbuettel). I got it work by adding it to the testRccpModule project as well. I'm damned if I can see what I am doing differently but that is my problem not yours! :-) Thanks

One thing that is worth noting is that **when** it is successful the class is available for tab completion in R Studio. A silly metric for success but a useful one

Comment: See my edits to my answer above, particularly Edit2.  It neeed `loadModule()`.

Comment: Dirk (@dirk-eddelbuettel) I found it needed two things. Firstly `loadModule()` as you suggested, but also, and forgive me but I can't find this in the vignette, it also needs to explicitly export the module in the NAMESPACE file, i.e. `export(Multicool)`


I would like to ask the difference between `loadModule(Multicool, TRUE)` and using the `.onload` function definition I gave above. I thought that this was supposed to take the list of modules from the `RcppModules` line in the DESCRIPTION file and load them all?

Comment: `NAMESPACE` is a red herring. That is an _R-side_ change (ie orthogonal to Rcpp Modules) which requires all to-be-accessed symbols to be listed. Moreover, it is an R change that was made since the vignette was written, and of course addressed in the working example I pointed you to, and which I also set for you four days ago.

Comment: Public holiday in New Zealand Dirk (@dirk-eddelbuettel) :-)

Comment: I should add that Dirk (@dirk-eddelbuettel)  is completely correct - the `NAMESPACE` addition only needs to be there if you want to work at the prompt with the exposed class. If you are just calling it inside your package functions then it doesn't need to be exported at all