# Expose simple C++ Student class to R using Rcpp modules

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to expose a simple Student class in C++ to R using Rcpp within a package. Here's my setup...

## src/

*Student.hpp*

```
//  Student.hpp

#ifndef Student_hpp
#define Student_hpp

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Student
{
public:

    // Constructor
    Student(std::string name, int age, bool male);

    // Getters
    std::string GetName();
    int GetAge();
    bool IsMale();
    std::vector<int> GetFavoriteNumbers();

    // Methods
    bool LikesBlue();

private:

    // Member variables
    std::string name;
    int age;
    bool male;
    std::vector<int> favoriteNumbers;
};

#endif /* Student_hpp */
```

*Student.cpp*

```
//  Student.cpp

#include "Student.hpp"

// Constructor
Student::Student(std::string name, int age, bool male) {
  this->name = name;
  this->age = age;
  this->male = male;
  this->favoriteNumbers = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
}

// Getters
bool Student::IsMale() { return male; }
int Student::GetAge() { return age; }
std::string Student::GetName() { return name; }
std::vector<int> Student::GetFavoriteNumbers() { return favoriteNumbers; }

// Methods
bool Student::LikesBlue() {
    return (male || age >= 10);
}
```

*glue.cpp*

```
// glue.cpp
// To use c++11, first run: Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")  ...or use a Makevars file

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "Student.hpp"
using namespace Rcpp;

//' Simulate a student
//'
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<int> simulate_student() {
  Student s = Student("bob", 10, true);
  return s.GetFavoriteNumbers();
}

// Expose (some of) the Student class
RCPP_MODULE(Student){
  class_<Student>("Student")
  .constructor<std::string,int,bool>()
  .method("LikesBlue", &Student::LikesBlue)
  ;
}
```

## R/

*student.R*

```
#' student
#'
#' A cool package
#'
#' Imports
#' @useDynLib student, .registration = TRUE
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
"_PACKAGE"

Rcpp::loadModule(module = "Student", TRUE)
```

After calling `devtools::document()`, I get the following NAMESPACE file

*NAMESPACE*

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(simulate_student)
importFrom(Rcpp,sourceCpp)
useDynLib(student, .registration = TRUE)
```

Now, after doing *clean and rebuild* from RStudio (i.e. `R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source student`) the package compiles and loads without issue. If I run the `simulate_student()` function, I get the expected result. However, when I try to make a new Student object with `stud <- new(Student)` I get *Error in .getClassesFromCache(Class) : object 'Student' not found*

This issue seems similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737317/using-rcpp-modules-to-expose-c-classes) but the accepted answer does not seem to solve my issue. Furthermore, I've looked into the [Annoy source code](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppannoy/blob/master/src/annoy.cpp) mentioned by Dirk, but I don't see any helpful differences between that code and mine except for the `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS_NODECL(AnnoyEuclidean)` snippets which I've tried placing in my code but also do not help.

Comment: Looking at [this guide](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf) as a reference, I don't see any sort of `unif_module <- Module( "unif_module", getDynLib(fx_unif ) )` statement to define the module in R land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glancing at the two packages, the main difference is related to how imports and exports of functions are setup.

In particular, both the `methods` and `Rcpp` package are missing as **full imports** in the `NAMESPACE` file. In addition, instead of individually exporting each function, there is a global export pattern used.

#### RcppAnnoy

```
useDynLib(RcppAnnoy, .registration=TRUE)
import(methods, Rcpp)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")          # export all identifiers starting with letters
```

https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppannoy/blob/1ce871ae52730098ddc7355597613e8313e23ac9/NAMESPACE#L1-L3

#### RcppStudent

roxygen2:

```
#' @useDynLib RcppStudent, .registration = TRUE
#' @import methods Rcpp
#' @exportPattern "^[[:alpha:]]+"
```

`NAMESPACE`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
import(Rcpp)
import(methods)
useDynLib(RcppStudent, .registration = TRUE)
```

https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-modules/blob/ca5d13ddd391d9fd4ffb50b4306131d2839f8af5/NAMESPACE#L5-L7

Answer (score 4):

The answer and comments to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293728/rcpp-exported-module-not-exposed) helped me.  It seems I needed to

1) change `@importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp` to `@import Rcpp` and
2) Add `export(Student)` to my NAMESPACE file (although I'm searching how to do this nicely with roxygen2 instead of inserting this manually)

After the above changes I can run

```
> stud <- new(Student, name = "Ben", age = 26, male = T)
> stud$LikesBlue()
[1] TRUE
```

UPDATE
It seems I can add `#' @export Student` to *student.R* for roxygen to automatically add the `export(Student)` bit to my NAMESPACE, that way I don't have to modify NAMESPACE manually.

UPDATE2
I've documented my steps in [this blog post](https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/exposing-a-cpp-student-class-with-rcpp/)

Comment: Thank you very much for documenting your steps that good!